# Database Migration from Oracle 11G to 12C on Sonarqube Version 5.0.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

Could you please advise me the impact of migrating database from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c for Sonarqube version 5.0.1.

Is this Sonarqube version 5.0.1 supported and tested on Oracle 12c ?

Please advise.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Anish Sethi.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on the ["Requirements" page of the SonarQube 5.1](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Requirements), versions of Oracle that are supported include:

> 12C [with Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 drivers since SonarQube 4.5 LTS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html) (port
>   number is mandatory in JDBC URL)

So SonarQube 5.0.1 should run fine on Oracle 12. Still:

- This does not necessarily mean that the migration from Oracle 11 to 12 is seamless - only your DBA will tell you this.
- SonarQube 5.0 is a quite old version, so you won't get a lot of help in case of trouble

Comment: Thanks for your response here, Fabrice. Database Migration will be done by Database team but we need to be sure that Sonarqube 5.0.1 version will run smoothly over it and projects would not be hampered. Also advise me on the post migration changes needs to be done inside Sonarqube version 5.0.1 in order to ensure everything runs as usual.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Sonarqube 5.0.1 is compatible with oracle 12C and my driver jdbc is  ojdbc6.jar which will also running fine for 12C . my question is do we need to make any other changes inside Sonar application or sonar properties  if The port number, Oracle SID and services does not changes for this upgrade ??